# Android - Passing ImageRessource-Integer arround

Tags: android, image, imageview

i really dont get any further with this, please take a look:
First i get an Integer (like "R.drawable.sic_pre") from an Base Adapter

```
ImageAdapter imad = new ImageAdapter(getBaseContext());
```

and passted to the next Activity

```
startActivity((new Intent(getBaseContext(),Card.class)).putExtra("draw", imad.mTlist.get(position)));
```

and tried to set the Ressource

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

    ImageView sel = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.selected);

    Integer src = extras.getInt("draw");

    sel.setImageResource(src);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card);
```

Does anyone have a clue whats wrong?
I cant set any Ressource to the ImageView

```
ImageView sel = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.selected);
sel.setImageResource(R.drawable.sic_pre);
```

doesnt work as well...

By the way, is it possible to get this "R.drawable.sic_pre" as String from the same as Integer? (Hope its understandable)

Greetings and thanks so far ueen

Comment: I think you should get NullPointerException. because findViewById() returns null before setContentView()

Comment: LogCat said somthing like this! Ok see it. Awesome, switched it and it works - Thanks alot!!!
Any idea on the second question?

Comment: i guess i just found it: getResources().getResourceName(extras.getInt("draw"));
but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `setContentView` before trying to `findViewById`

Answer (score 1):

your Q1: I can't set any Resource to the `ImageView`

Ans: `findViewById()` can only be called after set `setContentView()` ,either you will get null pointer exception.

your Q2: is it possible to get this `"R.drawable.sic_pre"` as String from the same as Integer?

Ans: no! because project's resources are referenced from **R.java** class and `"R.drawable.sic_pre"` is declared as variable name in **R.java** file, And names could not be called.

you can get the name of image stored in drawable `"sic_pre"` but not the complete name like `"R.drawable.sic_pre"`. to acheive that, you can concat String `"R.drawable."+getResources().getResourceEntryName(resId);`
or
`"R.drawable."+getResources().getResourceName(resId);`
but advice would be prefer this:

`"R.drawable."+getResources().getResourceEntryName(resId);`

Comment: Q2: actually its possible, i just found out. getResources().getResourceEntryName(srcp); gets, in this case, "sic_pre" and with getResources().getIdentifier() i can assemble the it

Comment: you cannot get complete name, like R.Drawable.sic_pre,from id.but using concatenation,you can get it.

Comment: fair enough for my needs